# Can an admin check in publishing pages for other users?

Tags: check-out, check-in

I know that those with Full Control can override a checkout by another user (which causes the user's changes to be lost), but can the Full Control users also check in those publishing pages on a SharePoint 2010 (so changes by another user aren't lost)? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you actually tried it yet?

Log in as a normal user. Edit a page. Save it, but don't check it in.

Log in as an admin, check the page in. See if the changes the user made are there.

My suspicions tell me that they will be there, as an administrator can always see the most recent version of a document, major or minor. The only thing is that the 'last modified by' field will be that of the administrator user.

Comment: Let us know what you find - I know it is difficult to find draft versions of documents without a published version for an administrator.

Comment: I just tested it and found that it can be checked in and as long as the person who checked out the file, selected "Save and Close" button and saved the changes in database, the changes are preserved when an admin checks in the page.

Answer (score 3):

There is an out of the box way of doing this -

Navigate to /_layouts/ManageCheckedOutFiles.aspx?List=ListGUID and take ownership for the Checked out files and check in

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by SharePoint Dude only applies to files with no checked in version.  It's accessible through the Library Settings page in the browser UI.

But James Love and Ashish Patel are right - as an admin, if you find a file and choose 'check in' the user's changes will be preserved.  (Tested using SP 2010.)  Sharepoint asks you to confirm if you want to override the check out but don't panic - all is well.